# How to convert left shoe to right shoe by turning it around in the fourth dimension?

Tags: geometry, symmetry

I read Steven Pinker's book : "How the Mind Works". It contains an interesting quote:

> I've studied three-dimensional mirror-images for twenty years, and I
> know mathematically you can convert a left shoe into a right one by
> turning it around in the fourth dimension....

I can't see how this can be done, can anyone explain?

Comment: Do you understand how to mirror-image a 2D structure by rotating it 180° in the 3rd dimension?

Comment: As in 3D you can rotate things around *a line*, in 4D you can rotate things around *a $2$-dimensional plane*, So take your shoe, take a plane within our 3D space, do the $180^\circ$ rotation and the shoe ends up on the other side of your chosen plane, reflected! (During the rotation, all sorts of things from the fourth dimension roll through our 3D space until you finish the full $180^\circ$ run, at which point everything in our 3D space is back - but reflected!)

Comment: This is analogous to what happens in 3D space when you reflect a plane by rotating it by $180^\circ$ in 3D around an (1D) axis that belongs to it.